# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find_all' Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

After cruising through about a dozen questions of the same variety, and consulting a coworker, I have determined I need some expert insight

```
with open("c:\source\list.csv") as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    for url in row:
      r = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
      tables = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"}).append
      for rows in table.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': 'Current_Releases'}):
          item = [].append
          for val in row.find_all('td'):
            item.append(val.text.encode('utf8').strip())
          rows.append(item)
      headers = [header.text for header in tables.find_all('th')].append
      rows = [].append
      print (headers)
```

So what I have here is : a csv file that has 30 URLs in it. I first dump them into Soup to get all of its contents, then bind the specific HTML element (the tables) to the tables variable. After this, i am trying to pull specific rows and headers from those tables.

According to logical thinking in my brain, it should work, but instead, i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Line 7 is

```
for rows in table.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': 'Current_Releases'}):
```

What are we missing here?

Comment: Why do you have `.append` at the end of `tables = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"}).append`?

Comment: What is `table`? A typo, I presume? Also, what's `[].append` supposed to mean? Please learn some Python before attempting to write any code.

Comment: Can you not be an ***hole about it? I'm learning by doing. Admittedly I am an absolute novice in python who's been tasked to create this program. i use append to append 30 tables to a single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some strange misconceptions about Python syntax. Four times in your code you refer to `<something>.append`; I'm not sure what you think this does, but `append` is a method and it not only must be called, with `()`, but it needs a parameter: the thing you are appending.

So, for example, this line:

```
 item = [].append
```

makes no sense at all; what are you expecting `item` to be? What are you hoping to append? Surely you just mean `item = []`.

In the specific case, the error is because of the superfluous `append` on the end of the previous line:

```
tables = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"}).append
```

Again, just remove the `append`.

Comment: Ooh, thanks for the insight on append. i was told to use append by my coworker to append multiple table results (From the 30 urls) to a single variable. When i run the code without the append at the end of the table variable, it works, but only pulls data from 1 table (The last one in the list)

I have a hard time believing this is impossible to accomplish in python

Comment: Of course it's not impossible to achieve; your problem is nothing to do with Python specifically, just general programming logic. If you want to loop through a bunch of items in a list, you need to define that list outside your loop, and append things to that list inside the loop.

Comment: I wish i knew more about general Python, i was thrown into this at random so im having to learn on the fly. I made an update to the parent post. I removed the append's in the code, and now im getting a brand new error at a different line.

Comment: When i run the first bit of code, with the .append at the end of the tables variable, and then print that result, i get a list of the 30 tables i am calling from the urls.